# How do I implement hook_form_alter() in a module?

Tags: forms, hooks

I am trying to alter a form for the *Question* content type, whose ID is *node-question-form*.

I set up a module and tried to implement `hook_FORM_ID_alter()`, but it's not invoked. Even the simplest implementation as the following is not working.

```php
function constellator_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  echo "alter the form";
  exit;
}
```

I have been stuck with this since this morning. Nothing is working for me.

Comment: Are you declaring your hooks in your module_name.module file? Did you rebuild your cache after declaring your hook? The basic declaration of hooks is pretty much the same as Drupal 7. Check: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks/8.3.x

Comment: This is not hook_FORM_ID_alter... this is hook_form_alter - where it needs to be modulename_form_alter. The arguments must also be $form, and `FormStateInterface $form_state`. That is the difference in Drupal 8. After adding it, you must clear the cache. PS: use a debugger. print;exit;die;... no good.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a working example I have pulled from a project and altered to have your module name.

Add this at the top of your .module file:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
```

Then copy this in

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function constellator_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Adding custom validation for the welcome page type field.
  if ($form_id == 'node_article_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_article_form') {
    // Do some stuff.
  }
}
```

I think most likely what you aren't doing is clearing the Drupal cache to register the hook.  You can click on "clear all caches".  Or better yet, install the drush command line utility and use "drush cr".

[image]

Comment: As of Drupal 8.7.3, this appears to be incorrect-- when I used `mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)`, I got `TypeError: Argument 2 passed to mymodule_form_alter() must be an instance of FormStateInterface, instance of Drupal\Core\Form\FormState given`. I changed my hook signature to `(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)`, and no more complaints.

Comment: This IS correct for all versions of Drupal 8 (and Drupal 9) - if you got that error it means your "use" statement is missing or wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you have set up a custom theme, then without adding any namespace requirement you can easily alter your form using `hook_form_form_id_alter()` in your theme_name.theme file.

```
function bootstrap_ga_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $base_url;
  $form['#validate'][] = '_bootstrap_ga_form_user_login_form_validate';
}
```

I added a custom validation to the user login form. *bootstrap_ga* is the custom theme name.

Comment: This won't work for Drupal 8.

Comment: Yes it will @Kevin - there's a missing global var, no type type hinting on the `$form_state` and a benign pass-by-reference, but none of those will stop the code from working. It's valid PHP, and valid per integration with the Drupal API. Not best practice, but definitely working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it in your custom module

Use the Below Namespace

```
    use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
```

Use this hook_form_alter for the particular node

```
    //constellator_form_node_question_form_alter
function modulename_form_Form_ID_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){   
  //echo <pre>; print_r($form); die;
}
```

And this hook will be used to edit the particular node form id

Comment: You can't pass form_state by reference. it is now an object, not an array, in Drupal 8. It must be passed in as `FormStateInterface $form_state`.

Comment: Also in a hook_form_FORM_ID_alter, there is no need to pass $form_id, you wouldn't need it.

Comment: Though its an object, we can use $form_state->getValue('paritcular field') to change the field . right!

Comment: While type hinting is considered best practice, there's no "must" about using it. Similarly objects are generally passed by reference, definitely so in this case, so there's no _need_ for the `&` before the parameter, but including it is no problem - it's still valid PHP. Also Drupal is passing the 3rd parameter to `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, so it's good practice for the hooks to include it in their signature too. While this answer doesn't really address the problem the question raises, it _is_ an alternative, it _is_ valid and it doesn't deserve these ill-considered pile-on down votes